# What type to use for a function arg accepting a value from a bitfield

Tags: c, split, byte, bit-fields

Say I have a struct that is of size 1 byte, it's declared by

```
typedef struct foo
{
  uint8_t fo1:2;
  uint8_t fo2:3;
  uint8_t fo3:3;
}foo;
```

Then I want to pass `fo2` as an argument to a function `func_foo(fo2)`, but I don't know how to declare that function, because `fo2` doesn't really have any type. Any idea how to do that? Appreciate any information!

Comment: It's the same as any `struct`. If you declare `struct bar { int b1; int b2; }`, you can't pass `b2` to a function with `func_bar(b2)`. You need to create an instance of the `struct` and pass the member of that instance to the function.

Comment: you mean using `func_foo(uint8_t fo2)` to declare the function, and when actually call the function, instead of passing an uint8_t argument, I can pass it a 3-bit variable? Is it safe to do so? Any thing I should keep in mind?

Comment: But I can declare a function as `func_bar(int b)`, because I can pass any int argument to it, instead of the one in the struct. The struct I put here is just to show why I would have a 3-bit variable.

Comment: The type of the function argument can be any integer type (or even any floating point type), since the compiler will implicitly convert `fo2` to whatever type the function takes.

Comment: My guess is that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the title is X and the body is Y. If that guess is correct then the answer to this question is, "Don't use bitfields to split a byte into bits."

Answer (score 1):

Since the struct members are declared to be `uint8_t`, that's the type you would use in the functions that you call.

```
void func_foo(uint8_t x);
...
foo my_foo = {1, 2, 3};
func_foo(my_foo.fo2);
```

The parameter can also be any wider type, e.g. `int` or `unsigned int`, since a `uint8_t` can be converted to those types without error.

Basically, just treat them like any other `uint8_t` structure members. The bit field means that they won't be able to hold the full range of 8-bit values, and it packs them all together in a single byte in memory. But when you're using the values, you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uint8_t`. It's large enough even if it larger than needed.

```
void func_foo(uint8_t fo2) {
   printf("%d\n", fo2);
}

foo bar = { 1, 2, 3 };
func_foo(bar.fo2);
```

I don't know how to declare that function